# при запуске "vagrant up" в гит баше (на виндовс 10) выскакивает ошибка

Tags: windows, composer, vagrant, виртуализация, homestead

при запуске в гит баше: "vagrant up" 
Выскакивает ошибка: 
"Bringing machine 'homestead-7' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
the following errors and try again:

vm:
* The host path of the shared folder is missing: D:/recording/Laravel"
 И что означает 'homestead-7'?
Пробовал и так: vagrant box add laravel/homestead-7, но ошибку ту же выдаёт...
Как сие можно исправить?